# Network analysis with package downloads

Tags: r, visualization

I have created a dataframe that contains a year's worth of data for package downloads in my country from CRAN and I now want to go about building a network of usage (I am not sure if network analysis is the correct term here).

There is a daily unique id assigned to each IP address (ip_id) so this combined with the day creates an overall unique ID for the set. I want to take each one of these instances and add it to a network so you will be able to see the cross usage between packages downloaded in these instances.

Each row in my set contains a value in ip_id and one package name (package). So if you downloaded 5 packages on this day - you will be 5 rows in the data.

I am assuming I will have to create some matrix that has a count of values that if car and crayon are selected they both get a one in their own match points on the diagonal and then also a 1 in the point where they correspond.

And then only after having created this I would be able to visualize it?

Added:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGwlB.png) See example of the data. So sourcetools, shiny, Cairo, htmlwidgets and DT would be one set for ip_id 2904 which means shiny x shiny should get 1 shiny x Cairo should get 1 and so and so forth.

If I can get this grid sorted out I should be able to visualize it.

Comment: A reproducible example would help

Comment: I have added data along with what I want to achieve. I don't have the exact know how yet to create it.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example. We can't help you work with data from a picture of it. If you need help with your visualization of a network, what have you done so far to get the network itself? It's easier to help if you've gone through some steps already

Comment: @GreyMerchant Just have a look at `dput`. In general please read [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R. Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., abstract from your real problem. It is much easier to help then...